# Metaverse Game - Scam?

Tags: unreal-5

I hope you can help me. I have invested in a metaverse game project which claims that 5 people are working full time on the project for 2 years already. Unfortunately in the last couple of days one team member got accused that he has stolen money from the investors. On the other side this team member accuses the rest of the team that they are lying and that a 14 year old boy is programming the game.
The investors have seen not many progress of the game so far, only a couple of short videos how someone drives in a car through the city. Now I am wondering if the game exists and if so is the game done with some kits or the parts are just bought. I saw that it is possible to buy for 100$ a metaverse world.
Would an expert see if its bought?
Which (technical) question can I ask to find out if they use a bought world and if everything is made from scratch?
Btw. they have collected around 3.3 Millionen $ for the game from investors :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They don't have 2 years of development on Unreal Engine 5, because Unreal Engine 5 because Unreal Engine 5 early access began only a little over a year ago. QED.

Comment: @Theraot They could have started dev in something else 2 years ago & since pivoted the project into UE5. That said, either case would seriously increase my skepticism.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what kind of due diligence was done before investing in a team of only 5 people trying to build something as large in scope as a "metaverse". It doesn't sound to me as though these allegations are the only significant risks here.

Answer (score 2):

**Would an expert be able to see if the world was bought?**

Maybe, but unlikely. It's possible that someone familiar with Unreal Engine 5 development & the market for related engine assets would recognize material they've seen before. The problem is that there's a lot of content out there. At the time of writing this, there are 1823 pieces of UE5 content available under the Environments tab in the Unreal Engine Marketplace. That doesn't include things like subcontracting the work out cheaply on freelance marketplace such as Fiverr.

If they've blatantly ripped off a well known show case piece from Epic (or something equally popular) making few to no changes, an expert would probably be able to spot it as a clone. It seems unlikely that a *single* expert would notice all possible recycled content. If *many* people saw the video the chance that someone might catch it increases. For instance, the discovery of [stolen art assets in Stellaris: Galaxy Command](https://www.pcgamer.com/the-stellaris-mobile-game-remains-offline-as-paradox-investigates-stolen-art-assets/).

**Which technical question could be used to determine if they used purchased assets or made the world from scratch?**

I would ask that question directly in an on-the-record setting / scenario.